# Use iteration to find a specific enum variant in a collection

Tags: rust, collections, enums, iterable

###### Setup

I have an enum whose variants have struct parameters, along with a vector of the enum:

```rust
struct A { x: i64, };
struct B { x: f64, },
enum E {
   One(A),
   Two(B),
   // maybe others
};
fn main() {
   let v = vec![ One( A { x: 10 } ), Two( B { x : 5. } ), /* others as well */ ];
   // ...
}
```

###### Task

Find in `v` an element of type `E::Two`.

###### Question

What is a concise, Rust-idiomatic way to do this?

###### Preferred approach

Use the iterable `find()` method, without deriving or implementing `Eq` and `PartialEq` on `A` and `B`, since *I want to find something of the same enum variant*; I don't really care about the variant's contents. In addition, deriving `Eq` and `PartialEq` is overkill, and can get painful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`matches!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.matches.html) macro to make this easy:

```
let found_item = v.iter().find(|i| matches!(i, E::Two(_)));
```

Using the macro is a more concise way to write this equivalent code:

```
let found_item = v.iter().find(|i| match i {
    E::Two(_) => true,
    _ => false,
});
```

In both cases, `found_item` will have type `Option<&E>`.  If you only want to know if such an item is present, you can either invoke `.is_some()` on this result, or you can use [`Iterator::any()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.any), which just returns a `bool` indicating if a matching element was found:

```
let is_found = v.iter().any(|i| matches!(i, E::Two(_)));
```

If you want to know the *index* of the found item, you can use [`Iterator::position()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.position):

```
let index = v.iter().position(|i| matches!(i, E::Two(_)));
```

`index` will be `Option<usize>`, which will only be `Some` if a matching item was found, and the contained `usize` value will be the index where the match occurred.

Comment: If you want to get the _content_ of the variant, use `flat_map()` with `match`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [std::mem::discriminant](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.discriminant.html) function:

```
impl E {
    fn is_two(&self) -> bool {
        mem::discriminant(self) == mem::discriminant(&E::Two(B { x: 0.0 }))
    }
}

v.iter()
.find(|e| e.is_two());
```

Comment: Thank you! This works, but it fails my admittedly unspoken desire not to construct a useless element merely for thecomparison. I had thought of something like this.

Comment: The `discriminant` documentation says: *"This can be used to compare enums that carry data, while disregarding the actual data."* - what exactly your use case is. So I think the *useless element* is necessary for the correct Rust syntax, but ultimately won't ever get constructed.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of these two possibilities uses the preferred approach.

### Loop, but not iterable `find`

I found this online somewhere (maybe even SO)

```rust
let mut index = 0;
let thing = loop {
    if let E::Two ( b ) = v[index] {
        break Some(b);
    }
    index += 1;
};
```

### Iterable `find`, but requires derivation

Implement or derive `Eq` and `PartialEq` for the types `A`, `B`, and `E`. Now it's as easy as

```rust
let Some(thing) = v.iter().find(|element| if let E::Two(b) = element {true} else {false})
    else {
        panic!("failure! :-("); // I know this won't happen
    };
```

Comment: You don't need to derive `PartialEq` to be able to use `if let` so you don't have to for your second example either.

Comment: Your first example will panic if it doesn't find the item you're looking for.

Comment: "You don't have to derive..." Weird. I wonder if my iterations of trying to find something that work left me with some cruft, but I could swear I tried it without them and it failed. I will revisit this later this evening when I have a moment and report back.

Comment: "Your first example will panic..." I was aware of that. I edited the question and answer several times before publishing, and apparently edited out a statement where I mentioned that I knew for a fact that the vector had at least one such element.

Comment: @cafce25 You're definitely right, and it should have been obvious. I don't know why I was under the impression that I had to derive those. Thanks!